# tensorflow 2,8 is installed in environment but when I run a notebook it prints out tf version as 2.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I created an environment using conda and installed tensorflow 2.8 and CUDA. I am using python version 3.8.1. In a terminal I activated the environment and typed pip show tensorflow and it prints out version 2.8 as expected. Now I open a jupyter notebook in that environment and run the code to check for the gpu and it finds it. Then I ran

```
 print(tf.__version__)
```

and it prints out 2.3.0. Why is it showing a different version?

Comment: Have you selected the correct kernel? Does `print(sys.executable)`  show the correct python interpreter being used?

Comment: Would you please tell all the steps you followed to create `vir_env` and to install `tensorflow` in your system?

Answer (score 0):

well I tried all kinds of stuff and could not solve the problem. So I decided to start from scratch. I remove anaconda/ I remove all versions of the CUDA toolkit and Cundd. I made sure all those directories were deleted.  I remove all the environmental variables from path that reference the cuda  paths. Then I re installed anaconda and create a new virtual environment(I forget I also deleted all anaconda generated directories). Then I followed the exact procedure to install tensorflow , the CUdatoolit and cudnn. Then all worked as it should.